# How to set a drawable as tabIndicator in android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I want to create a background shape to `tab indictor` in
 `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
but gradient do not work

tablayout in my layout is like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_category_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
                app:tabIndicator="@drawable/background_tab_selected"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />
```

and background_tab_selected.xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="@color/red"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:radius="33dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your code as well using this drawable file. Hope this helps.

```
var tab = fragment_category_tab_layout.newTab();
tab.setCustomLayout( R.layout.your_shape_drawable_file );
fragment_category_tab_layout.addTab(add);
```